# How to parse json and check the value of it?

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get a value of my json. First here is my json.

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "userData": {
        "user_id": "USER001",
        "username": "boby",
        "password": "c83e4046a7c5d3c4bf4c292e1e6ec681",
        "fullname": "Boby Kurniawan",
        "phone": "089688xxxxxxx",
        "profilpic": null,
        "status": null,
        "flag": 1,
        "tipe": "TP001",
        "Deskripsi": "Ini tentang gua",
        "Email": "boby@mail.com"
    }
}
```

Ok, for the first there will be 2 json, if the login success the json will look like above, but when it fails it will return

```
 { "status" : "false" }
```

**So I need to parse it right? so I add this line**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray status = jsonObj.getJSONArray("status");
```

**but I get this error**

```
unhandled exception : org.json.JSONException
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: please check my ans.

Comment: please check my ans with exception handling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `unhandled exception : org.json.JSONException`

**ANS :** you are getting that error Because `status` is string not a **JSON Array**

You should use **`jsonObj.getString("status")`** instead of **`jsonObj.getJSONArray("status");`**

Try this

```
try 
{


    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
    String status = jsonObj.getString("status");

    Log.i("status", "->" + status);

    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("userData");

    Log.i("user_id", "->" + jsonObject.getString("user_id"));
    Log.i("username", "->" + jsonObject.getString("username"));
    Log.i("password", "->" + jsonObject.getString("password"));
    Log.i("fullname", "->" + jsonObject.getString("fullname"));
    Log.i("phone", "->" + jsonObject.getString("phone"));
    Log.i("profilpic", "->" + jsonObject.getString("profilpic"));
    Log.i("status", "->" + jsonObject.getString("status"));
    Log.i("flag", "->" + jsonObject.getString("flag"));
    Log.i("tipe", "->" + jsonObject.getString("tipe"));
    Log.i("Deskripsi", "->" + jsonObject.getString("Deskripsi"));
    Log.i("Email", "->" + jsonObject.getString("Email"));

} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @YVS1102 Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> unhandled exception : org.json.JSONException

=> Because you are trying to get JSON Array, where as it's not JSON array but a field only.

Try:

```
String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
            JSONObject userData = jsonObj.getJSONObject("userData");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here "status" is not an Array, its String. Json Array should enclosed by [ ].
To get value of "status" you should use,

```
String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
```

Then you need to check status value.
Remember,

Json object enclosed by { }

Json array enclosed by [ ]

Also use try-catch block while fetching data,

```
try{
    String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to surround with a try/catch:

```
    try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            String status = jsonObj.optString("status");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: wrong ans check it **status** is a string not a json array

Comment: you're right... I forgot to change it after the copy paste :)
fixed...
also, best to use optString() and not getString()